# How to let user create a file with path-Objective c

Tags: objective-c, file, path, save

I need to be able to get the path defined by the user:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:Usersetpath  contents:data attributes:nil];
```

I need to define usersetpath

Comment: I'm afraid that SO doesn't use your code, so you will have to ask your  user what they want the path to be.

Answer (score 1):

That's an example of how choosing a path:

```
__block NSOpenPanel* panel= [NSOpenPanel openPanel]; // __block because it's used
                                                     // inside the block
__block NSString* path;
[panel setCanChooseDirectories: YES];
[panel setCanChooseFiles: NO];
[panel beginSheetModalForWindow: self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result)
 {
     if(result==NSOKButton)
     {
         path= [[panel URL] absoluteString]; // This is the path the user choosed
     }
     // Check also for the case that the user did hit the cancel button
     panel=nil; // The panel retains the block and the block retains the panel
                // so break the strong ref cycle by setting panel to nil.
 }];
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to say that you should append the filename to the path.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of "path from user"? 
You could use a textfield to let the user input a string and use it to prompt him for a path - but it is not clear what exactly your question is.

Also, note that in a typical iOS App, the user usually is not confronted with a path structure. You should actually hide paths from your user and store a file behind the scenes in an appropriate directory.

Edit: just saw you didn't specify iOS or Mac OS, so my above comment of course goes for iOS...